# The assertion of a compound function is equal to the assertions of its subs.

Tags: logic

My knowledge on formal logic is next to none, so some of this may be nonesense. I wish to write the following argument in a logical form:

## In simple words

If X does A, and Y does B, then a function (T) that calls X and Y does A and B

## In more logic form

Given we assert that:

- function X does A
- function Y does B
- function T calls X and Y

it follows that:

- function T asserts that A and B happen.

## And in verbose form

Consider a function *RemoveOddNumbersAndSquareTheEven* (which for a given input set of numbers outputs a set of only the even numbers but squared).

We assert that:

- For an input set of numbers it removes the odd numbers
- For an input set of numbers it squares the even numbers

Now two new function are introduced:

- *RemoveOddNumbers* for which we assert that:

  - For an input set of numbers it removes the odd numbers
- *SquareAllNumbers* for which we assert that:

  - For an input set of numbers it squares all numbers

My argument is that given that *RemoveOddNumbersAndSquareTheEven*:

- First calls *RemoveOddNumbers*
- Then calls *SquareAllNumbers*

It follows that *RemoveOddNumbersAndSquareTheEven*:
- For an input set of numbers it removes the odd numbers
- For an input set of numbers it squares the even numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you add the reasonable premise
$$\text{if T calls Z and Z does C, then T does C},$$
then you can infer that T does A and T does B. If you want to talk about compound results of "doing" like "A & B", you'll also need:
$$\text{if T does C and T does D, then T does (C & D)},$$
from which it now follows that T does A & B.